# input date into form using factory girl and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I have a Group model that I am testing using Request specs with Capybara and generating the data using Factory Girl

In my groups.rb factory...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group do
    sequence :name do |n| 
      "Group#{n}"
    end
    expiry Date.today + 2.weeks
  end
end
```

And use this in my groups_spec.rb...

```
describe "Groups" do
  describe "GET /groups" do
    it "an admin user can create a new group" do
      user = Factory.create(:user, :is_admin => true )
      group = Factory.build(:group)

      visit root_url
      fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
      fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
      click_button "Login"
      click_link "Groups"
      click_link "New Group"
      fill_in "Name", :with => group.name
      # need to change the below to use the Factory eg select Date.new(group.expiry)
      select "2014", :from => "group_expiry_1i"
      select "June", :from => "group_expiry_2i"
      select "1", :from => "group_expiry_3i"
      click_button "Create Group"
      page.should have_content("Group was successfully created.")
      page.should have_content(group.name)
    end
  end
end
```

So you see that this is not a good way to do the test as I'm not using the factory generated expiry. Does anyone know how to input the expiry date into the form properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just off the cuff without testing in Capybara, but I'd try:

```
select group.expiry.year.to_s, :from => "group_expiry_1i"
select Date::MONTHNAMES[group.expiry.month], :from => "group_expiry_2i"
select group.expiry.date.to_s, :from => "group_expiry_3i"
```

As long as those values actually exist in the dropdown it should select them correctly.

Comment: Had to change that last line to `group.expiry.day.to_s`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use select_date:

> select_date('31/12/2014', :from => 'Expiry')